# How can I keep only somes values in array, list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this array such as :

`a = numpy.array([10,15,20,36,58])`
`b = [10,15,20,36,58]`

And I would like to keep for a and b the values which are higher than 20 ie to get the following array/list :

`c = [20,36,58]`
`d = numpy.array([20,36,58])`

Do you know how can I do this ?

Comment: Python3 or python2? Do not tag both of them.

Comment: in either case, what have you tried thus far?  show your attempt and error(s).

Comment: If you are using NumPy arrays, then `c = a[a >= 20]` and `d = b[b >= 20]`.

Comment: you mentioned higher than 20 but your 'c' and 'd' includes 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10,15,20,36,58])
print(a[a >= 20])
```

Output:

```
[20 36 58]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
c = [k for k in a if k>=20]
d = numpy.array([k for k in a if k>=20])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[20, 36, 58]
array([20, 36, 58])
```